# Error while saving multiple accounts at a time

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page Controller="AddmultipleAccountsController">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listAccount}" var="acc">
<apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Account Number">
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.AccountNumber}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Account Type">
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.Type}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Industry">
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.Industry}"/>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="Add Accounts Row" action="{!addAccount}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Save Accounts" action="{!saveAccount}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

class

```
public class AddmultipleAccountsController {
Account account = new Account();
public list<Account> listAccount{ get; set; }

public AddmultipleAccountsController()
{
listAccount=new list<Account>();
listAccount.add(account);
}

Public void addAccount()
{
Account acc = new Account();
listAccount.add(acc);
}
public PageReference saveAccount() {
for(Integer i=0; i<listAccount.size(); i++)
{
insert listAccount;
}
return Page.Allaccountssaved;
}
}
```

I need to add multiple accounts in a page and save it. adding multiple rows is working fine. But when i try to add multiple accounts and click on "save" i am getting an exception.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   0019000001EJyEsAAL; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE,
>   cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id] Error is in expression
>   '{!saveAccount}' in component  in page
>   addmultipleaccountscontroller:
>   Class.AddmultipleAccountsController.saveAccount: line 19, column 1
>
> Class.AddmultipleAccountsController.saveAccount: line 19, column 1

when i am adding 1 record it is inserted succesfful, but multiple records by clciking on add and save i am getting exception

that is while inserting can any one help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply changing your `insert` to `upsert` will solve the problem. When you redirect (presumably to the same page), your view state is left intact by default. Since the prior account already has an ID, Salesforce is reminding you that you're trying to perform an update on the existing account, because inserts can never specify an ID, and an update must always specify an ID (but upsert can perform inserts and updates intelligently).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sfdfox, it is working fine now

Comment: Hi i want to add remove functionality in same table i am new to salesforce can u pls help me out sfdcfox